# How can I make sure that exactly one thread will do something?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have multiple threads which add items to a lock-free queue.
The items are then processed by another thread.

In the producer threads, I need to kick off the consumer thread, *but only if it's not already running or kicked off*.

Specifically:

```
public void BeginInvoke(Action method)
{
    //This runs on multiple background threads
    pendingActions.Enqueue(method);
    if (ProcessQueue hasn't been posted)
        uiContext.Post(ProcessQueue, null);
}
private void ProcessQueue(object unused)
{
    //This runs on the UI thread.
    Action current;
    while (pendingActions.TryDequeue(out current))
        current();
}
```

I'm using .Net 3.5, not 4.0.  :(

Comment: (I'm doing this because 100K calls to `SynchronizationContext.Post` end up killing the Windows message queue)

Comment: I'm curious why does the producer have the responsibility of starting the consumer?

Comment: @Conrad: The consumer is run on the UI thread, but only when there are items for it to process.

Comment: If that's the case, then the question & title are worded somewhat confusingly.  They make it sound like the consumer is running on a dedicated thread.

Comment: @Sean: I need exactly one thread to _start_ the consumer – to call `uiContext.Post(ProcessQueue, null);`

Comment: I like your infinite bow tie!

Answer (score 2):

I created the following class to do this:

```
///<summary>Ensures that a block of code is only executed once at a time.</summary>
class Valve
{
    int isEntered;  //0 means false; 1 true

    ///<summary>Tries to enter the valve.</summary>
    ///<returns>True if no other thread is in the valve; false if the valve has already been entered.</returns>
    public bool TryEnter()
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isEntered, 1, 0) == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    ///<summary>Allows the valve to be entered again.</summary>
    public void Exit()
    {
        Debug.Assert(isEntered == 1);
        isEntered = 0;
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
readonly Valve valve = new Valve();
public void BeginInvoke(Action method)
{
    pendingActions.Enqueue(method);
    if (valve.TryEnter())
        uiContext.Post(ProcessQueue, null);
}
private void ProcessQueue(object unused)
{
    //This runs on the UI thread.
    Action current;
    while (pendingActions.TryDequeue(out current))
        current();
    valve.Exit();
}
```

Is this pattern safe?
Is there a better way to do this?
Is there a more correct name for the class?

Comment: @SLaks it know that you're purposely avoiding using Monitor.TryEnter. Are you sure its worth it?

Comment: I just realized that I was misunderstanding the return value of `CompareExchange`.  I don't need the unique tokens.

Comment: @SLaks So if I understand correctly, if multiple threads attempt to call `BeginInvoke`, one will succeed at calling `uiContext.Post` and the rest will be ignored.

Comment: @Conrad: Exactly.  `ProcessQueue` will then dequeue all of the items.

Comment: @SLaks: This solution could leave your queue live-locked. Consider what happens when all items have been dequeued and the `while` loop ends, but just before `valve.Exit` is called something gets enqueued and `valve.TryEnter` fails leaving at least one item in the queue, but no signal for `ProcessQueue` is posted.

Comment: @SLaks: I have been thinking about this problem off and on all day. This is a **tough** nut to crack without resorting to hard locks.

Comment: Brian: You're right; thanks.  I should probably use a semaphore.

Comment: @SLaks: The Reactive Extensions download for .NET 3.5 has the `SemaphoreSlim` class in it. I am stuck on 3.5 for some of my projects as well and I have found this backport of the TPL to be very helpful.

Comment: @Brian: On further thought, I don't think a semaphore would help.  It would still have the same issue.

Comment: @SLaks: Yeah, I am having a hard time visualizing the usefulness of a semaphore now that you mention it. My first attempt this morning was focused on the usual no-lock pattern of spinning with `while` loops waiting for a virtual signal. I was thinking that signal could be embedded in the queue by enqueueing a `null` value to act as markers for getting the producer and consumer to rendezvous at certain points. It was all getting out of hand though. I then took a look to see if the `Barrier` class (again from the Reactive Extension download) could help. No luck there either.

Comment: @Brian: One option (I think) would be to forget about the locks and use the length of the queue.  If the queue is empty, call `Post()`.  However, `Enqueue()` doesn't return an atomic count.  I'm using [this queue](http://blog.boyet.com/blog/blog/testing-the-lock-free-queue/), and I'm not sure if it's possible to atomically check whether it was empty

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `Semaphore`. It will have a count of queue size.

Comment: No; I don't want to block at all.

Comment: If the consumer has nothing to do, it should exit.  It's running on the UI thread.

Comment: @SLaks♦ No problem! Basically Semaphore is that thread safe counter. You can use WaitOne(0) in order not to block it and check return value.

Comment: However, I'm still using .Net 3.5 and cannot use `SemaphoreSlim`, so I suspect that my solution is faster.

Comment: @SLaks♦ Your should be faster, definetely. But question is how much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
volatile int running;  //not a boolean to allow ProcessQueue to be reentrant.

private void ProcessQueue(object unused)
{
    do
    {
        ++running;
        Action current;
        while (pendingActions.TryDequeue(out current))
            current();

        --running;
    }
    while (pendingActions.Count != 0);
} 

public void BeginInvoke(Action method) 
{     
    pendingActions.Enqueue(method);
    if (running != 0)
        uiContext.Post(ProcessQueue, null); 
}
```

Comment: No, because `SynchronizationContext.Post` is asynchronous, so this might call `Post` twice in a row before `ProcessQueue` runs.

Comment: The point is that if you are queuing up a 100k posts then it is safe to assume the consummr thread is far slow then the producer threads. So most the time is spent in the consumption mode. So if I disable posting while consuming, I'll will cut down by orders of magnitudes, the number of extraneous posts.

Comment: Yes; that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for the consumer thread.  Then, producer threads can use that dispatcher's BeginInvoke() method to send data to the consumer thread.  The Dispatcher's queue takes the place of your pendingActions queue, and ensures that the consumer thread is only processing one work item at a time.

Rather than having the producer threads try to coordinate starting and stopping the consumer thread, just start the consumer thread before any producers have been started, and let it sit idle.  The Dispatcher should automatically take care of waking it up when needed.

Comment: This is the pattern that I'm replacing (except WinForms rather than WPF).  I had so many rapid-fire messages that the event queue got full.

Comment: Aha, gotcha.  I just dealt with a similar situation by upgrading to .NET 4.  :(   So the next thing I'm wondering is, if you're running into that situation then perhaps a little blocking is actually your friend?  After all, if they naturally tend to produce data faster than the consumer can consume it, then without any choking mechanism the size of the consumer's input queue will tend toward infinity.

Comment: My queue ought to be more scalable than Windows message queue; I'll find out when I run it.

Comment: Dispatcher uses its own queue implementation instead of the Windows message queue, and though I haven't run a direct comparison I do get the impression that it seems to behave better.  It might be worth giving it a shot before sinking time into a custom solution.